# How to resolve "logical replication target relation schema.table is missing some replicated columns" error in postgresql logical replication?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-12

I'm getting

> "logical replication target relation schema.table is missing some replicated columns"

error in logical replication. I'm using ***all table replication***. Due to some changes I wanted to delete a column from both subscriber and publisher. I dropped column from subscriber end first and then from publisher(it should've been other way around). But deletion from publisher took time and logical replication broke.

I tried adding columns at both end in every way. I also tried refreshing the publication at subscriber end. I also enabled and disabled the subscription. Still the postgres gives same error.

I'm using **PostgreSQL 12.3**.

How do I start the logical replication in such case without any data loss?

**-------------UPDATE---------------**

I resolved it by dropping the subscription and recreated it with `copy_data = false`. Later I copied the data missing on the subscriber side.
This was quite a headache and a long way to do this. Still looking for optimal solutions for this problem. Optimal solutions for this are welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add the column again at the subscribed database and wait until replication has caught up before dropping the column again.

Comment: Already tried that. It doesn't work.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is too little information. I claim that it should work.